# Turn off SSD on idle

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I know that one usually should’t make Windows turn off idling hard disk drives, as the repeated turning on and off is bad for the mechanics. But what about SSDs? My new notebook has an SSD, and the default energy saving options make the SSD turn off rather early (after 10 min on battery). Is that okay for the SSD, or should I rather disable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no moving components in an SSD so there's no mechanics to worry about.  Set it as low as you want.  Of course, for an SSD to perform optimally the firmware needs a chance to do background optimizing tasks.  So you might not want to set it too low for this reason.