# it possible to disable HDD after 20 min idle but not SSD (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, power-management

Hello my operating system is Windows 7.

I have 3 hard drives: 1 SSD (which hosts Windows), 2 HDD (just a file storage)
Is it possible to turn off HDD after some idle time but leave active SSD?

I checked windows 'Power management settings'. It has some option like 'Turn off hard disc after', but it doesn't have a selection which one to turn off.

Comment: As SSDs don't spin down, I hardly see it would matter

Comment: Related: [Turn off SSD on idle](http://superuser.com/questions/328710/turn-off-ssd-on-idle?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the turn off hard disc after x time option. There is no actual need to have a separate option for the SSD simply because it has no moving parts. 
HDDs have moving parts inside of them that usually spin with 5400 or 7200RPM. So when you spin the drive down it needs a few seconds to spin up. SSDs on the other hand don't have any moving parts and can be accessed almost instantly.